# PC periodically becomes semi-unresponsive

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 17.10

So I don't have any hard numbers on this, but it seems that once every 10 minutes or so, my PC will become semi-unresponsive for a few seconds, with for example, Firefox only managing to put out a few frames during the entire period where the issue occurs.  I've noticed that this tends to correlate with a CPU usage spike from the `Xorg` process, and I suspect that is related.

In case this is relevant, the PC has an Nvidia Geforce 1080 Ti GPU, using the 390.12 drivers from the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` PPA.

Anyone have any idea what could be happening here?

EDIT: I just tried reverting to the stock 384.111 Nvidia driver in the standard Ubuntu repositories to see if that would fix the problem, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: What kernel version is revealed using `uname -r`? Has this problem always been there or did it start recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to correlate the unresponsiveness to when Davmail was actively doing something, and sure enough [there's this bug in the Davmail bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/bugs/670/) which matches the symptoms perfectly.  The suggested workaround in that bug of setting `davmail.server` to `true` in the `.davmail.properties` config file seems to have eliminating the periodic unresponsiveness